# how to change style of tableview cell according to data which is in two array detail is below

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which has one section i want to decide in **cell for row at** method that this cell should be selectable or not. My data is coming from sqlite and it is being saved in two array one is **recommended** and second is **not recommended**. both array will have different size of data. so i want to disable cell when data is shown from **not recommended** and make it enable when it's from recommended array.so please tell me how to do this. If you want any further information please comment. i don't have enough code to post i need only heads up to do this task.

Comment: Use **one** array, create a custom struct or class as model and add a booelan property `isRecommended`. In `cellForRow` enable/disable the cell depending on that property.

Comment: little bit explanation with example if you don't mind. @vadian

Comment: Create a custom class. Add properties corresponding to the dictionary keys plus the `recommended` property. Map the dictionaries to instances of the class. Set the `recommended` property accordingly. In`cellForRow` set the appearance depending on `recommended`. That's basic object oriented stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you mapping items from both arrays into the table view? In other words how to you map an item in either array at index `i`, to a `UITableView` [IndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath)?

Specifying wether a cell should be selectable or not is done by overriding `UITableViewDelegate`'s [shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614988-tableview?language=objc)

Assuming section count is two and items at section index one are elements of the **not recommended** array:

**Swift 3**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        return indexPath.section !=1
    }
```

Comment: right now i have two section so mapping was easy but i want to convert it to one section and the items that were in second section should be disabled and background should be grey.

Comment: customizing a cell's looks should be done by cellforRowAtIndexPath. Selectability should be done as shown above.

Comment: you did not get my point i have two arrays one is recommended items and second is not recommended. i want to disable cell in cell for row using those two arrays so when recommended item cell comes it's enable and when not recommended cell comes it will be disable when tableview load for the very first time....

Comment: @HammerClass I understand your question perfectly welll. When your model changes, you will need to trigger reloadData on the main queue to trigger a refresh on the rows that have been modified. The selectability decision is done by overriding the method shown above, and changing a cell's looks because it is not recommended (ie. .backgroundColor = .lightGray) should be done in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method

Comment: Sorry dear but i am not getting you point. please can you explain with little example?